# Cannot capture XML returned by SQL Server stored procedure using Java

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, jdbc, jtds

I am trying to run a SQL Server 2014 stored procedure from Java (Spring) code and get some xml results.

When I run this in a SQL client e.g. RazorSQL I get a bunch of xmls (which is expected because the there are multiple stored procedures within it, that returns those xml).

Here is the Exec call from my SQL client:

> EXEC    [dbo].[sp_GetType]
>           @TRAN_ID = 42
>           @QUAL_ID = 0

GetType does a RETURN 0 at the end (so basically if all steps succeed, it returns 0)

This opens multiple tabs in my client with the xmls.

And one example stored procedure within GetType has these lines:

```
 SELECT TOP 1 ModifiedBy = CASE WHEN @IS_ID = 1         FROM TABLE23.dbo.TRX
 TrxId WITH (NOLOCK)        WHERE  @DD_ID = @TRAN_ID   
 FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
```

My goal is to capture all the xmls returned by GetType into a List of objects.

Here is my dao:

> ```
> private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
>
> @Autowired
> public TransactionDao(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
>     this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
> }
>
> @Transactional(readOnly = true)
> public List<Object> getTransaction(Integer tranId, Integer qualId) {
>     Object dt = new Object();
>     List<Object> resultList = (List<Object>) jdbcTemplate.execute(
>             new CallableStatementCreator() {
>                 public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
>                     String storedProc = "{call sp_GetType(?,?)}";
>                     CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(storedProc);
>                     cs.setInt(1, tranId);
>                     cs.setInt(2,  qualId);
>                     return cs;
>                 }
>             }, new CallableStatementCallback() {
>                 public Object doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement >     cs) throws SQLException,
> DataAccessException {
>                     List<Object> results = new ArrayList<Object>();
>                     cs.execute();
>                     if(cs.getMoreResults())
>                     {
>                         ResultSet rs = cs.getResultSet();
>                         while(rs.next()) //rs has only one record
>                         {
>                             InputStream in = null;
>                             Clob clob = rs.getClob(1);
>                             in = clob.getAsciiStream();
>                         }
>                         rs.close();
>                     }
>                     return results;
>                 }
>             });
>     return resultList;
> }
> ```

I'm using the jtds 1.3.1 driver (I tried connecting using mssql-jdbc but no luck).
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This is unclear.  What about your code is not working? What errors do you get?  _"My goal is to capture all the xmls returned by GetType into a List of objects"_ -- do you have code written, or are you asking us to write the code for you (which is off-topic)?

Comment: _What about your code is not working?_ Its not being able to capture the xmls

Comment: _do you have code written_ the one I've posted is the code I've written and I'm asking for ways to get the xmls